# ASIHttpRequest,XML Data

Tags: iphone, objective-c

hell friends,
i am using ASIHTTPrequest protocol to fetch XML data 
i am also adding libxml2.dylib framework into my project.
also set headersearch path.

but still i get 61 errors.
what's the problem???

Comment: You should post the offending code so we can help you.

Comment: @Hiren, Hi, in my project I am using ASIHTTPrequest, too and GDataXML and I needed to add the libz.1.2.3.dylib. I don't know if this will help you. Please post at least some of the errors.

Comment: Thank You for u all for your reply i get point i am missing some framework to add in my app

Comment: Have you changed the header search path?

Comment: yes i am changing the path with this string -- $(SDKROOT)/usr/include/libxml2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for ASIHTTPRequestyou have to add `CFNetwork.framework, SystemConfiguration.framework, MobileCoreServices.framework, CoreGraphics.framework and libz.1.2.3.dylib`.

The setup instruction is here: http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/Setup-instructions